# How to plot multiple signals in one graph with same xlab and ylab in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I want to present 7 different signals for male against female, that means 14 signals in a graph with 7 rows and 2 columns, also make them all share the same xlab and ylab.

i used grid.arrange() and when i plotted for female alone (7 signals) it was so messy only the titles appeared and the signals are not showing. 
each f here is a ggplot() of a time series, i have 7 others for males, like m20,...,m80 .

```
grid.arrange(f20,f30,f40,f50,f60,f70,f80, nrow = 7)
```

So, how would i make the graph suitable with 14 signals (7 for females to the left and 7 for males to the right)?? and make them all share the same one xlab and one ylab?!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using ggplot to plot all your data in one plot object and then use facet_grid to make individual panels for sex & signal..if you share the code & sample dataframe you are currently using I can offer more help

Facet_grid(signal~sex)